# How to use a different set of assets for a Rails controller or action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, asset-pipeline

Assets are not loading correctly because Rails is looking for a folder that's named corresponding to the `id` of the object that's being requested. For example:

When I request `/blog/1/edit`, Rails is looking for assets in `/blog/1/[whatever].css`.

All of my assets are in the `public` folder. For some reason only the edit action breaks the asset path:

[image]

Is it possible to just use the assets in `/public/blog` for all `BlogController` activity?

**Relevant Information**

**routes.rb**

```
resources :posts, path: 'blog'
get 'blog' => 'posts#index', as: 'blog'
```

**public assets folder structure**

```
public/
  blog/
    css/
    fonts/
    js/
```

Comment: code? why should rails look into blog/1/ ? never had before

Comment: @huanson -- Hey! I'll get some code up in a second. Thanks for stopping by to check this out.

Comment: your assets needs to be in /app/assets/js /app/assets/css /app/assets/fonts.

please show how you included them in your layout

Comment: As @huanson asked, what do your header tags look like?